# QueryDSL MathExpressions.log on SQL Server 2008

Tags: querydsl

It looks like QueryDSL MathExpressions.log creates SQL statements with LOG(float_expression, base), while this is only supported in SQL server 2012+

Is there another way to create 10-base logarithm that works with SQL server 2008?

At runtime this exception is thrown:
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The log function requires 1 argument(s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/990) will be fixed in the upcoming 3.5.1 release of Querydsl.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way to create 10-base logarithm that works with SQL
>   server 2008?

Yes. In general,  log<sub>b</sub>x = log<sub>k</sub>x  / log<sub>k</sub>b

So, you can compute the 10-base logarithm of x as  `= LOG(x) / LOG(10)`

where `LOG(x)` is the natural logarithm function in SQL Server 2008. This is sometimes denoted by `LN()` [for log natural]

Comment: Thanks, but it looks like the LN() function was introduced in 2008R2. In 2008 LOG() is the natural logarithm and LOG10() is the 10-base logarithm.

Comment: MathExpressions.ln() creates a statement with LN()

Comment: Sorry if this was not clear. My question is how to get the 10-base logarithm on SQL server 2008 USING QueryDSL. QueryDSL's log() function uses LOG(float, base) which is not available on 2008, and QueryDSL's ln() function uses LN() which is not available on 2008.

Comment: I have opened a [Querydsl issue](https://github.com/querydsl/querydsl/issues/990)